# Creating a database using Connector/NET Programming?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How to create a database using connector/net programming? How come the following doesn't work?

```
    string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=mysql;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string s0;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hello`;";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, conn);
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to execute the MySqlCommand. Now you just create one, but it doesn't execute your query.

Try this:

```
conn.Open();
s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hello`;";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: will this work in VS 2013 or do you have to attach a few Dll first?

Comment: I tried this in my c# program but did not work. You must use ` rather than ' around the database name. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You need to execute the command and also make sure to properly dispose objects:

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=mysql;";
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `hello`;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: will this work in VS 2013 or do you have to attach a few Dll first?

Answer (score 1):

execute your command and try this function

```
public void createDatabase(string server, string port, string database, string username, string password)
    {
        string connectionstring = string.Format("Server = {0}; Port ={1}; Uid = {2}; Pwd = {3}; pooling = true; Allow Zero Datetime = False; Min Pool Size = 0; Max Pool Size = 200; ", server, port, username, password);
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = connectionstring })
        {
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand { Connection = con })
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();

                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    msgErr(ex.Message + " connection error.");
                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    command.CommandText = @"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @database";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", database);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();//Execute your command
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    msgErr(ex.Message + " sql query error.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private dBf As String = "Empresa"
    Private str As String = "Server = localhost; uid=root; pwd=;Database=mysql; pooling=false;"
    Private Cmd As MySqlCommand
    Private Con As New MySqlConnection(str)
    Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Con.Open()
            Cmd = New MySqlCommand("Create Database If Not exists " + dBf, Con)
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() : Con.ChangeDatabase(dBf)
            Cmd = Con.CreateCommand
            Cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Empleado" &
             "(Id Char(10)  COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci Not Null," &
             "name  VarChar(50)  COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci Not Null," &
             "email VarChar(50)   COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci Not Null," &
             "website VarChar(50)  COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci Not Null," &
             "Primary Key(id)) ENGINE=MyISAM"
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Registros, ok!!!") : Con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is no formatting. It does not help at all to solve the problem. Please remove or improve your answer thanks.