# C# Connect to a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database without any success. I found a lot of examples but neither of them worked for me.

I installed the NuGet Connector.Net package and used the following code:

```
  string DBcon = "Server=localhost;Database=world.sql;Uid=root;Pwd=password;";

    using (MySqlConnection db = new MySqlConnection(DBcon))
    {
        db.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Success");          
    }
```

I even installed MySQL Server but it still doesn't work. I get the following error: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'world.sql'

Comment: Well the error message tells you the problem, fix that!

Comment: `world.sql` probably contains SQL code to create a db or some tables in an a DB.  MySQL Dbs do not typically have a .sql extension - at least none of mine do.  You'll also have to create accounts and permissions for a new DB with something like MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

world.sql is a file name not a database.

you need to change

```
string DBcon = "Server=localhost;Database=world.sql;Uid=root;Pwd=password;";
```

to

```
string DBcon = "Server=localhost;Database=databaseName;Uid=root;Pwd=password;";
```

### edit 1

this should help you run the SQL

```
conn.Open();
s0 = File.ReadAllText("path to file") 
cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

which is an adaptation of the answer from this link 
[create database in mySQL from .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532531/creating-a-database-using-connector-net-programming)

Comment: How can you possibly know it's a file?

Comment: @DavidG are you really asking that question?  in order for mySQL MSSQL or Oralcle RDBMS to read a file, it needs to have the .sql file extension.   a database is never ended with .sql. a database file is typically ended with mdb for microsoft access, mdf and ldf ( database and log files for MS SQL Server) dbf for Oracle and mfy for MySQL. So thats how i know

Comment: Yes, I am full aware of how database files are named, but there is no way to know that this is the reason why.

Comment: I think Simon is right and OP didn't even opened the sql file inside a real database server en just tries to read the backup file or something

Comment: Also, the file extension does not magically make any RDBMS able to read it, it's just a convention that allows you to link a file with an application.

Comment: the end of the error message he gets is "Unknown database 'world.sql'" take a look at this link and then rethink your position http://fileinfo.com/extension/sql

Comment: I downloaded a sample database named "world.sql".
I'm used only to SQLite where I put the path to database in the connection string.

Comment: Pointing me at extension information says you are not reading what I am saying. I give up

Comment: @Mark you should learn how to use MySQL before posting such basic questions here.

Comment: @Mark you need to run the SQL thats with in the file that will create the database for you by the sound of it.  Open the file in Notepad or whatever Text Editor you are running and one of the first lines will be Create Database database name ....

Comment: Why go to the trouble of using C# to open the file? Especially when OP can't even connect to the database...

Comment: You said above that the database contains a "CREATE DATABASE" statement, yet OP can't connect with C# until the database exists. And commenting here calling anyone stupid is going to get you banned pretty quickly if you're not careful.

Comment: you really need to read what i put, i will copy and paste what i said, and it does contain a grammatical issue, but here it is.. "you need to run the SQL thats with in the file that will create the database" so go slowly and youll see what i said