# Creating MYSQL database with C# paramatized

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am having an error with this code:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MySQLDatabase'' at line 1"

```
string connectionString = string.Format("SERVER = {0}; Port = {1}; User = {2}; Password = {3}", server, port, username, password);
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd;
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string createDBCommand = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @database";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(createDBCommand, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", database);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

this is the code that produces the error, at the ExecuteNonQuery() statement.
database is a value that is comming from a class.Properties.Default value. and is currently the string "MySQLDatabase"

I am currently using MySQL server 5.7, and am using a create statement that is similar to the example in the documentation, except for the fact that I am using a parameter.

Comment: Tried running the same command directly in workbench?

Comment: Check your query to make sure there is nothing wrong with the query. By the way you should dispose the connection and command. Have a look at this example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532562

Comment: Thanks, I am a but new to using MySQL, that is simpler for deposing the connection then the method I was using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MySQLDatabase'' at line 1"

Note, that these aren't double quotes around *MySQLDatabase*, but two single quotes. That gives a vital hint here. The substring of a statement where an error occurred is enclosed in single quotes in the error message. That is, the substring reads 'MySQLDatabase', the other pair of single quotes is in that substring.

Your query, as the DBMS sees it, looks like

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'MySQLDatabase'
```

and the single quotes aren't allowed here. They would be right if we talked about a value in form of a string literal though.

Parametrized queries just don't work properly for replacing object names (in DDL statements), they aren't meant for that. Here you'll have to concatenate the name to the string of the query yourself. And add checks, that the data is sane.

Comment: This answer worked really well and seems the simplest. As the data I am dealing with is completely internal I don't have to worry about sqlinsertion or anything of that nature, so Do not need the security that comes from using parameters.